# Import error while installing django using pip

Tags: python, django, pip

command on windows : pip install django
Got the below error
**import error: No module named commands.install**

Comment: which version of python? run `python -V`

Comment: Hi Ayush, I am using python 2.7.11

Comment: Try to remove your previous installation and install again using: sudo apt-get install python-pip

Comment: @AdrianoSilva he's on windows

Comment: @Sourav try upgrading pip, or reinstall completely

Comment: Which python distribution you're using? If you're on ActiveState try pypm install django